# Asking about the logic of python decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x

there's something I've been asking myself a lot: the porpouse of decorators is to change a function without changing its code. This is the basic appearance of a decorator:

```
def a(b):
   def c():
      print("This is a change")
      b()
   return c
@a
def b():
   print("Whatever b does")
```

So, why are decorators like that and not like this?:

```
def b():
   print("Whatever b does")

def a(b):
   print("This is a change")
   b()
```

It much easier this second way and it changes the function as the first way, but with less code.So why? Thanks!